# Regex: Using Regex to only allow simple arithmetic

Tags: javascript, regex

So, I have a validator and a `string.replace()` to protect my basic `textarea` input.

My validator looks like this:

```
Validators.pattern('-?[0-9]+([-+*/]?-?[0-9])*')
```

Essentially, I want to allow all simple arithmetic.

Examples:

```
2*2-2
2*2--2
-2**2--2
```

I don't want to allow multiple symbols beyond * or + like *** or +++

Examples of what should be allowed for the validator:

```
+
+- (addition of a negative)
-
-- (evaluated as +)
/
*
**
```

Everything outside of `integer (valid expression) integer (valid expression) integer etc.` should be replaced with "". (just as an added precaution incase the validator fails):

```
+++ => +
--- => -
*** => **
/// => /
+-  => -
*/  => // (not sure what to do with this)
```

I have something like this, but it needs tweaking to be a whitelist:

```
unsafeCalculation.replace(/-?[0-9]+([-+*/]{1,2}?-?[0-9])*/, '');
```

Example:

```
2**2--2---2+++2///2 => 2**2+2-2+2/2
```

Let me know what you think would be the best `replace` regex.

Comment: You need to explain what the expected behavior of your code should be and how it is deviating from that behavior. Also, your requirements are less than clear. Your second and third examples have a `--` operator, which contradicts what the next sentence (which says that the only multiple symbols are `**` or `++`). What's `++` supposed to do? Also, what about "3 + -2" which makes perfect sense but wouldn't be accepted by your stated rules (at least once the spaces were removed).

Comment: I have updated the question, great points!

Comment: Analyzing some string against some "grammar" (rules for how it is supposed to be constructed, sometimes called a "language") is called "parsing". Regexp is not at all well suited to doing "parsing", except for trivially simple languages. The language you are trying to parse is probably beyond the capabilities of regexp; if not now, it will be the next time you add a new feature. Therefore, don't try to use regexp for this. Write a parser, either yourself, or using a simple parser toolkit, or some kind of existing tool such as perhaps math.js.

Comment: Okay, I will try a parser first.

Comment: adding to what @torazaburo mentioned Regex is bad in this case due to its backtracking, it's very slow here compared to whatever parsing algorithm you use.

Comment: @TedHopp Okay, what if I just want to allow the pattern `number expression number eg. 123*123+123` and replace anything that falls outside of this pattern?

Comment: @torazaburo See comment above, looking for the pattern `number expression eg([-+*/]) number eg. 123*123+123` and remove everything else?

Comment: What's your syntax for `number`? Would it be `\d+` or maybe `[1-9]\d*`, or `[-+]?[1-9]\d*`? Do you also want to allow decimal point, thousands separator, etc.? What can `expression` be? Just `[-+*/]` or do you want to allow other operators? If you eventually want to allow parentheses, then it's provable that you can't use regex for that without bounding the number of nested parentheses, and even then it's impractical. Define your grammar and write (or use) a parser. A recursive descent parser is pretty easy to write from scratch if you don't want to use a library.

Comment: @TedHopp I think just `[1-9]\d*` for numbers, no decimal, and expression is just `[-+*/]`

Comment: So just try that. For a regex use `[1-9]\d*[-+*/][1-9]\d*` (or `[1-9]\d*([-+*/][1-9]\d*)?` if you want to allow just a single `number` or `[1-9]\d*([-+*/][1-9]\d*)*` to allow zero or more operators, each followed by a number). You might have to include anchors at either end of the regex to force the complete string to match.

Comment: @TedHopp So, my issue now is, I want to replace everything that doesn't fit. So I can start with `allCalculationString.replace(/^[^1-9]+ | [^1-9]+$ | (something here that will remove duplicate expressions eg: ** ++ -- etc.) /g, '')`

Comment: On a slightly different topic, the user interface paradigm wherein the computer randomly and capriciously changes and rewrites the user's input to match some idea it has of what the input "should" be, is and has always been a horrible idea. Instead, display clear error/warning messages and let the user fix it.

Comment: @torazaburo Yeah, great point, I already have a validator that lets users know what is allowed... I just wanted another layer as backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, what you're describing is very close to (if not quite exactly) parsing. RegEx is terrible for parsing. For a good parsing tutorial, look here: http://lisperator.net/pltut/parser/

That said, this is simple enough that you could get away using RegEx. Instead of trying to create an end-all-be-all regex, you can replace multiple times on the same string. This makes it clearer to read and write.

e.g.

```
unsafeCalculation
  .replace(/[+]{2,}/g, '+')
  .replace(/[-]{2,}/g, '-')
  // etc,.
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I decided to go with something a bit more compact: `trimCalculationString.replace(/([-+*/])(?=.*?\1)/g, '')` though I did decided to break up the removal of unwanted chars, then trim, then repeats.

Comment: Sure. Just remember that the hardest part of RegEx isn't writing it -- it's debugging it and remembering what it does. :)